# MongoDB getting size of cursor takes a long time if size is 0

Tags: mongodb, timeout

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using keyword queries against a MongoDB. If I search for things that exists in the database everything works ok, but if I search for things that don't exist, or I have a typo in my query the appilcation basically crashes.

The query is as simple as this:

```
var query = Query.And(Query.Matches("text", searchText)
```

Where searchText is what's being written into the searchbox in the UI.

To check the size of the cursor I've tried implementing this:

```
       if ( cursor.Size() == 0)
         {

             MessageBox.Show("Your search did not return a match. Please search for  
             something else.");                
             return database;
         }
```

But the system takes 10-15 minutes to evaluate that the size is 0, compared to the 0.5 seconds if the size is 1 or more.

So do anyone have any suggestions? Either a better way of checking the size of the cursor or some kind of function that makes the method time out and tell the user that no match was found?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

As requested added the explain for something that should and something that shouldn't exist

```
   db.docs.find( {text:   "a"}).explain
     function (verbose) {
/* verbose=true --> include allPlans, oldPlan fields */
var n = this.clone();
n._ensureSpecial();
n._query.$explain = true;
n._limit = Math.abs(n._limit) * -1;
var e = n.next();

function cleanup(obj){
    if (typeof(obj) != 'object'){
        return;
    }

    delete obj.allPlans;
    delete obj.oldPlan;

    if (typeof(obj.length) == 'number'){
        for (var i=0; i < obj.length; i++){
            cleanup(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    if (obj.shards){
        for (var key in obj.shards){
            cleanup(obj.shards[key]);
        }
    }

    if (obj.clauses){
        cleanup(obj.clauses);
    }
}

if (!verbose)
    cleanup(e);

return e;
 }


   db.docs.find( {text:   "fgrgfk"}).explain
     function (verbose) {
/* verbose=true --> include allPlans, oldPlan fields */
var n = this.clone();
n._ensureSpecial();
n._query.$explain = true;
n._limit = Math.abs(n._limit) * -1;
var e = n.next();

function cleanup(obj){
    if (typeof(obj) != 'object'){
        return;
    }

    delete obj.allPlans;
    delete obj.oldPlan;

    if (typeof(obj.length) == 'number'){
        for (var i=0; i < obj.length; i++){
            cleanup(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    if (obj.shards){
        for (var key in obj.shards){
            cleanup(obj.shards[key]);
        }
    }

    if (obj.clauses){
        cleanup(obj.clauses);
    }
}

if (!verbose)
    cleanup(e);

return e;

   }
```

Update 2: Overview of indexes:

```
         db.docs.getIndexes()

  {
          "v" : 1,
          "key" : {
                  "_id" : 1
          },
          "ns" : "tweet_database.docs",
          "name" : "_id_"
  }
```

Comment: Is that field indexed? How large is the collection? Could you run the query from the console using `explain` for a word that exists and doesn't? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/query-plans/

Comment: Which language and driver are you using? And is your "text" field even indexed?

Comment: To be honest I don't know if it's indexed cause I'm only using the data and I don't have anything to do with the database itself.

I added the explain now, but they look the same, don't know what that means though.

But does the possible lack of indexing explain why it takes longer to evaluate the size of the cursor when it's 0 compared to any other number?

As for language and driver, it's C# and 10G driver.

Comment: Another update, it appears that only the ID field has been indexed. Could this cause the current issue?